# Dynamically declare string variables

Tags: c#

I want to declare string dynamically for example

```
int i =2;
```

then declare two string

```
string str1 ="";
string str2 ="";
```

So basically I want to declare string based on `i`.

Comment: There are Lists and Arrays - use them.

Comment: Umm, google `arrays in c#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `array`, you can't do it like that:

```
int i = 2; // get the input from somewhere

var values = new string[i];
```

But that doesn't mean it's not possible.You can even create dynamic assemblies,classes,properties,if you really want to.See this documentation for more details: [Emitting Dynamic Methods and Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use Lists like this...

```
        List<string> MyStrings = new List<string>();
        Console.Write("Enter the number of strings you want to create > :: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            MyStrings.Add("String"+i.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var str in MyStrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```